# Счётчики в базе данных

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Возникла необходимость подсчёта кол_ва статей, вопросов, задач пользователя, создал для этого отдельную таблицу, где для каждого пользователя есть своя строка со статистикой.

Тогда возник вопрос что будет эффективнее отправлять запрос к бд для повышения счётчика после добавления статьи например, или поставить триггер в самой бд, чтобы она повышала счётчик?

Comment: Триггер будет работать независимо. В java вы можете забыть обновить счётчик при неверном архитектурном решении. Хотя триггеры в БД разделяют логику приложения, что тоже не очень хорошо

Comment: @ArchDemon, все таки вопрос был задан с точки зрения производительности

Comment: С позиции архитектуры вынос этого функционала в триггер - размывание логики и лучше этого избегать. С позиции гарантий целостности данных, как уже заметил @ArchDemon, наоборот лучше триггер. А с позиции производительности существенной разницы не будет. То есть однозначного ответа нет, вам придётся выбрать решение более подходящее именно для вашей системы.

Comment: Сбалансированое решение - уход от запросов к процедурам. Логика не размывается (наоборот - централизуется), целостность обеспечивается (надёжнее - только FK), производительность почти не страдает...